# Qt: closing modal dialog closes the program

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

In my Qt program I have 2 windows (main and child window). In the program, only one of these windows is shown at a time. Main window has a slot, which creates a modal dialog. Now, let's say a signal from a button click in child window is sent to that slot. In that case, main window is hidden and child window is visible. The dialog is displayed just fine, but when the dialog is closed, the program closes as well, although the child window is still visible. The expected behaviour is that after closing the dialog, the child window is still visible and the program is running. What could cause this behaviour, and how could it be fixed? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: any debug output or sourcecode to work with?

Comment: "the program closes as well, although the child window is still visible" makes no sense. If program's window is shown, it's definitely still running. Did you mean that the child window is still set to be visible but it disappears and the program terminates?

Comment: What I meant, is that the child window and the dialog are both visible, so dialog isn't the last window. Closing it shoildn't close the program. What you described is exactly what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);` on your QApplication instance.