# Qt closing modal dialog closes application

Tags: qt, dialog, qt4

Similar issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19710930/2800918), but the working answer there does not help me.

My app has a grid of QFrames.  Right clicking in a frame brings up a context QMenu as a child of the QFrame.  One of the menu options creates a modal QDialog child of the menu, and displays it using;

```
void ContextMenu::saveAs( )
{
    QPointer<MyDlg> myDlg = new MyDlg( this );
    myDlg->setModal(true);
    myDlg->show();
}
```

When the dialog OK button is clicked, the MyDlg::accept slot is activated, it does it's thing, calls close(), the QDialog goes away, and the app keeps running.

When the dialog Cancel button is clicked the Dialog goes away, and the app exits.

I have tried implementing the MyDlg::reject slot, and having it call close().  In that case, the Dialog will not go away and the app remains running.

I have tried attaching to the reject via the UI editor, which created MyDlg::on_buttonBox_reject(), and had that call close().  Results in the original behavior - app exits.

I have tried using myDlg->exec(), instead of myDlg->show().  Results in the original behavior - app exits.

Finally, I have tried the above individually, and in concert with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712085/2800918), but that had no effect on the results.

I have also read through whatever Qt forums I could google up with these terms, and they all have variations on the things I've tried above.

The code doesn't use QApplication, it uses QMainWindow.  I overrode event(), and this is the list of events that occur;

```
2014-10-27T13:55:15.032Z  Event: ParentChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.033Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.033Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: StyleChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: WindowIconChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.034Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.035Z  Event: ChildRemoved
2014-10-27T13:55:15.053Z  Event: DynamicPropertyChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.053Z  Event: PaletteChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.053Z  Event: StyleChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.053Z  Event: ParentChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.057Z  Event: WinIdChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.057Z  Event: Polish
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: PaletteChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: DynamicPropertyChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: PaletteChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: ChildPolished
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: ChildPolished
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: ChildPolished
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: Move
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: Resize
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: ZOrderChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.058Z  Event: Show           << Show main window
2014-10-27T13:55:15.059Z  Event: CursorChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.059Z  Event: ShowToParent
2014-10-27T13:55:15.059Z    HApplication  entering event loop...
2014-10-27T13:55:15.059Z  Event: PolishRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:15.059Z  Event: LayoutRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:15.059Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.061Z  Event: WindowTitleChange
2014-10-27T13:55:15.072Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.072Z  Event: ChildAdded
2014-10-27T13:55:15.619Z  Event: UpdateLater
2014-10-27T13:55:15.619Z  Event: UpdateRequest   
2014-10-27T13:55:15.620Z  Event: LayoutRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:15.636Z  Event: Resize
2014-10-27T13:55:15.636Z  Event: Move        << QDialog displayed
2014-10-27T13:55:15.670Z  Event: LayoutRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:15.670Z  Event: UpdateRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:15.672Z  Event: LayoutRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:15.672Z  Event: LayoutRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:16.064Z  Event: WindowTitleChange
2014-10-27T13:55:23.570Z  Event: Enter
2014-10-27T13:55:23.570Z  Event: HoverEnter
2014-10-27T13:55:23.570Z  Event: HoverMove
2014-10-27T13:55:23.571Z  Event: WindowActivate
2014-10-27T13:55:23.571Z  Event: ActivationChange
2014-10-27T13:55:23.571Z  Event: UpdateRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:23.578Z  Event: HoverMove ...snip...
2014-10-27T13:55:24.026Z  Event: HoverMove  << Cancel button clicked
2014-10-27T13:55:24.450Z  Event: Leave
2014-10-27T13:55:25.679Z  Event: WindowBlocked
2014-10-27T13:55:34.651Z  Event: WindowDeactivate
2014-10-27T13:55:34.651Z  Event: ActivationChange
2014-10-27T13:55:34.654Z  Event: UpdateRequest
2014-10-27T13:55:41.098Z  Event: WindowUnblocked
2014-10-27T13:55:41.099Z    HApplication  leaving event loop...
2014-10-27T13:55:41.102Z  Event: ChildRemoved
2014-10-27T13:55:41.102Z  Event: ChildRemoved
2014-10-27T13:55:41.102Z  Event: ChildRemoved
2014-10-27T13:55:41.102Z  Event: ChildRemoved
2014-10-27T13:55:41.102Z  Event: ChildRemoved
2014-10-27T13:55:41.102Z  Event: ChildRemoved
2014-10-27T13:55:41.102Z  Event: ChildRemoved
```

I'm stumped as to what to try next.  Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that "app exits" isn't a crash... Subclass `QGuiApplication` and reimplement the destructor to put a breakpoint in it, then look at the stack trace produced from the rejected dialog. Without knowing the order of events, we can't fix the issue.

Comment: @cmannett85 added some event info to question. I tried to install an event filter on QCoreApplication::instance() as described [on this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html), but got none. Gdb indicates normal program exit.

Comment: @cmannett85, I seem to have solved this by dumb luck.  Trying to center the dialog over the main window wasn't working so I changed the parent from the context menu to the cm's parent. If you understand why this fixed it, please post as answer.